# Change Image by clicking on list Item

Tags: javascript, html

Something is up can't seem to get this to work, need some help. This code is suppose to allow you to hover over the list items changing the image as you hover over individual li items, (eg is you hover over January you would see the Jan-Cal.png image) doesn't seem to work

The Orange Crunch

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
$("li").bind("mouseover",function(){
$("img").hide();
$("#img"+this.value).show();
console.log(this.value);
    });​

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>


    <div>
    <img id="img0" src="../../WDC/Jan-Cal.png"  />
    <img id="img1" src="../../WDC/Feb-Cal.png"  />
    <img id="img2" src="../../WDC/March-Cal.png"/>

    </div>

    <ul>
    <li value="0">January</li>
    <li value="1">February</li>
    <li value="2">March</li>

     </ul>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You can't put multiple elements with same ID in HTML.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I change it so that each one has a different id and now all of them are appearing easy to place them but i cant seem to change the image onclick of the individual list items they appear when i hover over the word months

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the condition?

Comment: I'm confused. When I click on January, what should happen? When I click on February, what should happen? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up an event listener on the `<ul>` and then get the element that was clicked. Try structuring the list like so:

```
<ul id="months">
   <li><img class="jan" src="../../WDC/Jan-Cal.png" /></li>
   <li><img class="feb" src="../../WDC/Feb-Cal.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Then set up a onClick event listener:

```
function changeImage(evt){
   // Get the image that was clicked.
   var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

   // Then get the src or get the class
   var targetSrc = target.src;
   var targetClass = target.getAttribute("class");

   // Do more processing here...
   // Then you can change the src of the image if need be.

}

var months = document.getElementById("months");
months.addEventListener("click", changeImage, true);
```

That way it doesn't matter how many elements are in the un-ordered list. You can check for the class or the src string. Note: This event handler only works for some browsers. You'll have to make a cross browser event handler.

Comment: It doesn't work when I hover over the word "Months" it gives me the drop down list but it just gives me the december calendar. I have multiple classes throughout the page I'm not sure what seems to be blocking it from changing the image when i click on each specific month

Comment: Is there a reason that you have the anchor tag in the list item before the un-ordered list? Could this be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/wzQPq/

The javascript/jquery:

```
var images = $('#images').find('img');

//hide images at the beginning
images.not(images.first()).hide();

$("#legends").on("mouseover", 'li', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $this_val = $this.val();

    $("img").hide();
    $("#img"+$this_val).show();
});​
```

The html:

```
<div id="images">
<img id="img0" src="../../WDC/Jan-Cal.png"  />
<img id="img1" src="../../WDC/Feb-Cal.png"  />
<img id="img2" src="../../WDC/March-Cal.png"/>
</div>

<ul id="legends">
<li value="0">January</li>
<li value="1">February</li>
<li value="2">March</li>
 </ul>
```

The problem is that you're `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

`this.value` doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `value` isn't a jQuery object property. `val` is what you're looking for. It's a method and not a property - that's what the parentheses in front of it are for.
2. `this` points to something else other than the element. `$(this)` is what you should be using.